# What am I Missing here?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, datatables

So I finally solved my pagination jquery datatable problem. But then new problems arised. It still loads the 1000 rows of data it's not following the number of data that I wanted. So I figured that it's throwing hidden variables on the server side such as the *sEcho* , *iTotalRecords*, *iTotalDisplayRecords* and etc.. What I did was to find a guide about it which is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359750/jQuery-DataTables-in-Java-Web-Applications). I studied article and tried to integrate it to mine.

Here's the integration:

for the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "populate/pull", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void populatePull(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    JqueryDataTableModel param = DatatableParams.getParam(request);
    String sEcho = param.sEcho;
    int iTotalRecords=0; // total number of records (unfiltered)
    int iTotalDisplayRecords; //value will be set when code filters companies by keyword
    List<KspeakPull> pullList = pullServive.viewAllPull();
    System.out.println("Viewing all");
    iTotalDisplayRecords=pullList.size();
    if(pullList.size()< param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength) {
        pullList = pullList.subList(param.iDisplayStart, pullList.size());
    } else {
        pullList = pullList.subList(param.iDisplayStart, param.iDisplayStart + param.iDisplayLength);
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject();
    jsonResponse.addProperty("sEcho", sEcho);
    jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalRecords", iTotalRecords);
    jsonResponse.addProperty("iTotalDisplayRecords", iTotalDisplayRecords);     
    jsonResponse.add("aaData", gson.toJsonTree(pullList));
    System.out.println(jsonResponse.toString());
    response.setContentType("application/Json");
    response.getWriter().print(jsonResponse.toString());

}
```

The jQuery table model copied this one from the guide, I'm wondering if this is the problem because he didn't use any getter/setter:

```
public class JqueryDataTableModel {

    // / Request sequence number sent by DataTable, same value must be returned
    // in response
    public String sEcho;

    // / Text used for filtering

    public String sSearch;

    // / Number of records that should be shown in table

    public int iDisplayLength;

    // / First record that should be shown(used for paging)

    public int iDisplayStart;

    // / Number of columns in table
    public int iColumns;

    // / Number of columns that are used in sorting

    public int iSortingCols;

    // / Index of the column that is used for sorting

    public int iSortColumnIndex;

    // / Sorting direction "asc" or "desc"

    public String sSortDirection;

    // / Comma separated list of column names

    public String sColumns;
}
```

and the datatable params:

```
public class DatatableParams {

    public static JqueryDataTableModel getParam(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getParameter("sEcho") != null
                && request.getParameter("sEcho") != "") {
            JqueryDataTableModel param = new JqueryDataTableModel();
            param.sEcho = request.getParameter("sEcho");
            param.sSearch = request.getParameter("sSearch");
            param.sColumns = request.getParameter("sColumns");
            param.iDisplayStart = Integer.parseInt(request
                    .getParameter("iDisplayStart"));
            param.iDisplayLength = Integer.parseInt(request
                    .getParameter("iDisplayLength"));
            param.iColumns = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iColumns"));
            param.iSortingCols = Integer.parseInt(request
                    .getParameter("iSortingCols"));
            param.iSortColumnIndex = Integer.parseInt(request
                    .getParameter("iSortCol_0"));
            param.sSortDirection = request.getParameter("sSortDir_0");
            return param;
        } else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Imported the following scripts in my JSP:

```
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/jquery-1.8.3.js'/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/bootstrap/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/bootstrap/js/pull-populate.js' />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' />"></script>
```

and my ajax codes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tablediv").hide();
 $("#showTable").click(function(event){
       $.get('populate/pull',function(responseJson) {
           if(responseJson!=null){
               $("#pulltable").DataTable({
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "populate/pull",
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",          
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "aoColumns": [
                                  { "mDataProp": "id" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "alias1" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "alias2" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "alias3" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "alias4" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "keyword" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "charNo" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "korWord" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "korCharNo" },
                                  { "mDataProp": "charTotal" },
                              ]    });
            }
        });
        $("#tablediv").show();          
 });      });
```

When running it causes a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
 String sEcho = param.sEcho;
```

So, What am I missing here? Obviously it's not receiving the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
&& request.getParameter("sEcho") != ""
```

You are using `!=` which will check reference equality, rather than value equality (see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)).

Since this will be `false`, your `else` will always return `null`. You then do `String sEcho = param.sEcho;`, and `param` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
&& !request.getParameter("sEcho").equals("")
```

This should compare the value and is a better practice than using `!=`. `Equals` compares the values and you should not have that kind of problem anymore.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielOshiro